# If feature 1 and feature 2 are using data driven and, feature 1 fails for one data, how to ignore the run for feature 2 for same data

Tags: api, automation, karate

In Karate API automation ,in Feature A , which is running through data driven , if the scenario fails for one data (say DATA ONE), how to stop a subsequent feature B, that has dependency on feature A(i.e,the functionality of what is done by feature A, for example,let's assume that feature A is for customer creation and feature B is for ticket booking, if Feature A fails for dataOne, I don't want the ticket booking to happen for dataOne), from running for the data (DATA ONE)

Feature A - should run first and uses Data driven

Sample data used in Feature A(EX: CustomerCreation.feature):

DATA ONE - Scenario fails
DATA TWO  - Pass
DATA THREE - Pass

Feature B - should run second and uses Data driven

Sample data used in Feature B (EX: TicketBooking.feature):

DATA ONE - should not run
DATA TWO  - Should Pass
DATA THREE - Should Pass

Comment: How does Feature A call Feature B? If that's not the case, you can't be sure that Feature A will run before Feature B.

Comment: @Adrien using KarateOptions .

Comment: @KarateOptions(features= {"featureA","featureB"})

Comment: In that case, you don't have any link between featureA and featureB. It could very much be possible that featureB launches before featureA, and that might cause problems with your tests. I don't really know if the parallel runner depends on alphabetical order or something else to pick the order in which the tests are run, but I'm not sure that you should rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what I explained in comment, since you edited your question, maybe I can give you some answer.

If you create Customers 1 2 and 3 in feature A.
Let's say Customer 1 isn't created, but 2 and 3 are
In feature B, before you try to book a ticket for each Customer, you should simply check if that Customer exists, with a GET request for example.